# Struggling to mount network drive on VM

Tags: mount

I am running (L)Ubuntu on a VM and am trying to permanently mount a network drive attached to my DDWRT router. I have had no issues mounting it on numerous RPis and Windows PCs. However, I keep getting an error that there is no such file or directory, despite it being listed with `smbclient`:

Command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=mediadrive //192.168.1.1/MediaDrive /mnt/MediaDrive
```

`/mnt/MediaDrive` does exist as does `//192.168.1.1/MediaDrive`

Here is the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add vers=1.0:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=mediadrive,vers=1.0 //192.168.1.1/MediaDrive /mnt/MediaDrive
```